# Function pointers table in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, interpreter, forth

I'm doing a Forth interpreter in C. I can't decide how to better implement the Forth dictionary.

```
struct Word {
   struct Word* next;
      char* name;
      int* opcode;
      // int arg_count;
}
struct Dictionary {
    struct Word words;
    int size;
}
```

`opcode` is a sequence of codes - functions of word. So each **opcode[i]** corresponds to some function. I suppose it should be some table with elements *[opcode<->function pointer]*. But how to implement it?

We don't know the size of function. We can't use **void*** (or we can?) since we must somehow having only opcode execute the function.

What should I do?

Comment: This is not at all clear.  A table mapping integers to function pointers is perfectly possible.  What is the specific problem here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, function's signatures are different

Comment: "struct Word words;" (in contrast to "struct Word *words;") normally is no good idea.

Comment: @greensher In that case you could use a union if there are only a few different function types, or rewrite the functions that take fewer parameters to take a few extra ones to make them compatible, or write wrapper functions. Function-pointers and void-pointers are incompatible, you can't have a blanket all-purpose function-void-pointer. Or, forget the function-table alltogether and use a `switch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some variation on this definition is quite common in traditional Forth implementations:

```
typedef int cell;
typedef void code_t (struct Word *);

struct Word
{
  char name[NAME_LENGTH];
  struct Word *next;
  code_t *code;
  cell body[];  /* Upon instantiation, this could be zero or more items. */
};
```

The dictionary will then be a list linked through the `next` pointer.  The words are allocated sequentially, interleaving the `struct Word` header, and the `body` data.

To execute a word, call `word->code(word);`.  The function pointed to by `code` can then decide what to do with `body`.  The body could be data, or it could be what you call "opcodes".

A colon defintion will have `code` pointing at something like this:

```
void docolon (struct Word *word)
{
  /* IP is a variable holding the instruction pointer. */
  rpush (IP); /* Push the current instruction pointer to the return stack. */
  IP = (struct Word *)word->body; /* Start executing the word body (opcodes). */
}
```

Whereas a primitive word, e.g. `+` would look like

```
void plus (struct Word *word)
{
  cell n1 = pop();
  cell n2 = pop();
  push (n1 + n2);
}
```

Comment: IP = (struct word *)word->body;

Answer (score 1):

All of this below is based on an assumption: You want to declare function pointers.

```
typedef int (*OPCODE)(char *);

struct Word 
{
    struct Word* next;
    char* name;
    OPCODE *opcode;
    // int arg_count;
};
```

`opcode` is a function pointer to a function that returns an integer and takes a `char *` as the argument. A really good page of short tutorials on function pointers is *[The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)* by Lars Engelfried.